# Creating a stepobject fails

Tags: yii2, codeception

I'm currently building a project on top of yii2 and I've got a strange error when trying to create a new stepobject.

cept is an alias and leads to vendor/bin/codeception

```
(15:01:22) [yii] cept generate:stepobject acceptance Admin
Add action to StepObject class (ENTER to exit): X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.6
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in 
<b>*snip*/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/QuestionHelper.php</b> on line 
<b>158</b><br />
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
Aborted
```

I'm using the latest version of yii.

Comment: show the codem where you create the stepobject

Comment: that's a snippet from the bash console

Comment: What versions of symfony/console and codeception have you got installed?

Comment: Symfony console 3.3.0 and codeception 2.3.3. So the latest versions were installed by composer